# How to dynamically change meta tags for crawlers on a static vue application?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, facebook-opengraph, vue-router, meta

I am building a static vue website with some routes. In one of these routes, I use an Http GET request to get data from a remote server. Something like this:

```
www.example.com/products/1/
```

This checks my remote server for a product with an id of 1. The product is then returned, and I use that data to populate the template. The only issue is the meta tags. Ideally, I would like to set my meta tags using the data I receive from my server, especially the open graph tags, so that the Facebook share box is properly configured.

However, I am getting the data from the server in my created() function, so changing the meta tags from the component does not seem to work for Facebook and Google crawlers.

What is the correct way to tackle this issue? Thanks!

Comment: What approach are you currently using to update the meta tags that is having an issue? What does "does not seem to work" mean?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think there's a CLIENT SIDE only solution to this, you either need to pre-render the page with meta tags, or use SSR (essentially the same thing in regards to this issue), changing meta tags at run time won't help you.

Comment: You can do this and here is how: https://alligator.io/vuejs/vue-router-modify-head/
Move your fetch-data-method to `beforeCreated`, in `created` - fill meta tags.

Comment: @AndrewShmig, I'd love to be proven wrong (as I'm having the same issue), but I think what you say is incorrect, unless you use pre-rendering. Bear in mind that the OP asked in relation to crawlers.